# List of chat rooms that subscribed on tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, chat, tag-wiki, feed

I can see which tags particular room is subscribed on. For example, [Stack Overflow на русском](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/22462/stack-overflow--?tab=feeds) is subscribed on [russian-stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/russian-stackoverflow).

> [image]

But on the tag page there is no information about subscribed chats.

Is it possible to add this information on the tag information page?